# How to pass arguments as a text file to perl script in runtime

Tags: perl

I have a perl script file called as xyz.prl.
If I run this in command prompt, then it will ask for some command line inputs.
So I have placed all the inputs in a separate file called as input.txt.
Then I used the following command in the command window.

```
D:>xyz.prl < input.txt
```

But it is not taking the values from the file input.txt and going into infinite loop by asking for the first value.

If I give only xyz.prl , Then it is asking for the input values.  and accepting the value which I give manually.

Actually I have to develop a VC++ (MFC) dialog based application and using windowsXP. In that I have to use system command to run this xyz.prl and I have to pass all the arguments as a text file (input.txt). I am very sorry to inform u that the xyz.prl is highly secured file and I cannot share the code.

If I give xyz.prl directly on command prompt, it is asking for the input values one by one. But using system call I cannot send the values like that.

I am entirely new to perl. So please let me know the command that I have to pass to system command.

Thanks,

Segu
Thanks
Segu

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some code?

Comment: That is called blocking, not an infinite loop.  An infinite loop consumes CPU time, blocking doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

With the shell redirection `xyz.pl < input.txt` I believe you are giving the input from the file through STDIN, which can be read with `<STDIN>` or the diamond operator `<>`.

However, the generic way to read data from a file is:

**Usage:**

```
$ xyz.pl input.txt
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use ARGV::readonly;

while (<>) {
    # $_ variable contains each line from the file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because input.txt won't be passed as a parameter -- it will be accessible as a stream. In the example below it's the "while(<>)"

http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~svhwan/prodScript/perlGettingInput.html

```
#!/bin/sh
#! -*- perl -*-
eval 'exec $PERLLOCATION/bin/perl -x $0 ${1+"$@"} ;'
if 0;

$okayToPrint = 0;
while (<>) {
    my $currLine = $_;
    if ($currLine eq "WorldBegin\n") {
        $okayToPrint = 1;
    } elsif ($currLine eq "WorldEnd\n") {
        $okayToPrint = 0;
    } else {
        # some line between WorldBegin and WorldEnd
        print $currLine;
    }
}
```